# how to import a module that using another module at the grandparent directories in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, init, relative-import

I'm trying to run a python file that imports a module using other modules in the grandparent folder. The file structure is:

```
directory_0
   |
   directory_1
   |   |
   |   directory_2
   |      |
   |      __init__.py (define the method A and import another method B from file_2.py)  
   |      |
   |      file_1.py
   |
   directory_3
      |
      file_2.py (define the method B)
```

I want to run `file_1.py` that *imports method A* defined in `__init__.py`, and `__init__.py` it *imports method B from file_2.py*.
I'm currently at `/directory_0/directory_1/directory_2` to run the command `python file_1.py`. It throws `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named directory_3.file_2`
How to make it run? and which path should I go to run this script (file_1.py).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need `__init__.py` in all 1-3 directories.

Try to use next syntaxis

import ...directory_3.file_2

Answer (score 0):

my final approach is import in the way:
in file_1.py:

```
from directory_1.directory_2 import A
```

and jump to the path that can access all children modules to run file_1.py as a module:
from `/directory_0` run by `python -m directory_1.directory_2.file_1`

Comment: That's the correct solution (I guess you added the init.py files in the intermediate directories also)